# Global Counter Variable in a PHP/HTML web application

Tags: php, html, mysql, global-variables

I am coding a web application to practice implementing MySQL databases, so I am not concerned with the *"correctness"* or *"efficiency"* of what I'm trying to do.

---

**Question:**

The primary key for the database with User's information is the **Member ID Number**, but upon registering the member does not know their ID number as it should be automatically assigned. The user just has to enter their name, address, etc. to register.

The way I have it working now is  just taking all the information from an input form and using that to add an entry to the MySQL table. The issue is that I need the Member ID Number, which I can't get from the user.

Is it possible to have a global counter variable that increments every time a member is registered? i.e. the first member is given ID 1, then 2, then 3, etc.

If so, how would I implement it? I'm comfortable with global variables and such in other programming languages but have never used PHP/HTML before.

Thanks!

Comment: Either use an AUTOINCREMENT id column on your database, or a GUID value if you don't want predictable member id numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using MYSQL you can set your column in the table that stores the ID as `AUTOINCREMENT` refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) for more information on how to set a column to autoincrement.